# Windows Web Server 2008 R2 Max RAM 16 GB?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, 64-bit, windows

This is page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I see: Windows Web Server 2008 R2
Limit on X64: 32 GB
In my system display, I see: **Only 16 GB are usable**. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

[image: Only 16 GB are usable]

Specs:
PowerEdge 2970 - Quad Core AMD Opteron蒂 2372HE 2.1GHz 4x512K Cache 1Ghz HyperTrnsprt

Comment: That is odd indeed, what's your server make/model & exact memory loadout?

Comment: Have you got any additional switches (e.g. /PAE, /3GB, etc.) for your OS booting entry in boot.ini file?

Comment: @Sergey: Server 2008 and up no longer use `boot.ini`.  The closest analog would be the [Boot Configuration Data store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like the BIOS is configured to keep a spare stick of RAM or something similar.

Comment: @Sergey & @JScott, and in addition to the whole `boot.ini` thing not existing for years, the `/pae` and `/3GB` switches have *never* worked on amd64 platforms.

Comment: What is the model for your motherboard and what memory slots are inserted? You may need to use Registered DDR3 ECC (RDIMM) memory, as is the case with ASUS P7F-E?

Comment: Cucumber can I ask you to please calm down, read our FAQ and try to understand how this board works as right now you're making something of a fool of yourself. This is a Question and Answer site, not a forum or social network, if you want to make a comment then add it as a comment. I'm moving this to being a comment, as for your other 'answer', its just not.

Comment: Thank you, I do not understand it from the beginning

Comment: By any chance did you happen to upgrade this server from Windows Web Server 2008 to Windows Web Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2):

Run "perfmon /res" on your server. Check the memory tab. I'm betting that there's 8GB specified as hardware reserved. This could be because of actual hardware needs, but I think it's more likely that you're running a memory configuration that your motherboard doesn't support. Here's a Microsoft KB article that may shed some light on your situation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610